# Why does CF UAA check_token endpoint need a clientId/clientSecret?

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, cloudfoundry-uaa

CloudFoundry's UAA has a RemoteTokenServices class (part of Spring oauth2 too) that does the authorization token validation by going to the UAA server's check_token endpoint.
UAA has sample **api** and **app** applications that serve as a resource server and a client application respectively.

From the sample **api's** spring-servlet.xml:

```
<bean id="tokenServices" class="org.cloudfoundry.identity.uaa.oauth.RemoteTokenServices">
    <property name="checkTokenEndpointUrl" value="${checkTokenEndpointUrl}" />
    <property name="clientId" value="app" />
    <property name="clientSecret" value="appclientsecret" />
</bean>
```

Do you know why this class (and the check_token endpoint that needs these values encoded in an Authorization header) needs a clientId and a clientSecret? It seems to me that it puts dependency on the client application from the resource server. How can I use multiple client applications if one of the client secrets is "hardcoded" here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out myself by reading the UAA [documentation](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa/blob/master/docs/UAA-APIs.rst#oauth2-token-validation-service-post-check-token) thoroughly, and I still think that it's confusing in the UAA sample applications:

- The clientId and clientSecret values should be the client id/secret of the **api application** (*api/apiclientsecret*) in the sample as the resource server should authenticate **itself** to the UAA server with basic auth when calling the check_token endpoint so the UAA can be sure that the request was made by a valid, registered resource server.
- To be able to do that, the resource server must also be registered as a client in UAA with **client_credentials** as authorized-grant-type.
- The token that should be checked is sent in the POST request body.